# Calling Model.refresh_from_db() not working after saving model with ForeignKey assignment

Tags: python, django

I'm writing some tests for a quiz/test application for Django.
The relevant model is `PreguntasPrueba`, which is an appearance of a question in a quiz, and holds ForeignKey relations with the Quiz (`Diagnostico`) model, the Answer (`Respuesta`) model (This is the user's response), and the Question (`Pregunta`) model.

relevant fragment of **models.py**:

```
class PreguntasPrueba(models.Model):
   prueba = models.ForeignKey(
        "Diagnostico", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False,
        related_name='preguntas_usadas'
   )

    pregunta = models.ForeignKey(
        "Pregunta", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='apariciones'
    )

    respuesta = models.ForeignKey(
        "Respuesta", 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='seleccion_usuarios'
    )
```

In test.py, I create in setUpTestData a bunch of Pregunta instances (each with a set of Respuesta instances associated and then create a Diagnostico instance.

In one of the test, I try to assert that my method for validating correct answers is working, by assigning an answer instance to the question appearance  instance (refer above model), but when doing so, I call `save()` and `refresh_from_db()` on the instance, and the ForeignKey assignment does **not** work. I'm completely lost as to why this happens... Any help would be appreciated.

relevant fragment of **test.py**:

```
# get all the questions used in the quiz instance (I'm certain there are only 3)
preguntas = self.diagnostico.preguntas_usadas.all()

# assign individually corresponding Respuesta (answer) instances (This is kinda simulating a user's choice
preguntas[0].respuesta = Respuesta.objects.get(pk=2)
preguntas[1].respuesta = Respuesta.objects.get(pk=5)
preguntas[2].respuesta = Respuesta.objects.get(pk=14)

# I iterate over the queryset to save it and reload it for future use
for pregunta in preguntas:
    pregunta.save(update_fields=['respuesta']) #saving
    pregunta.refresh_from_db() # supposedly refresh?? But I don't know what I'm doing wrong...
    print(pregunta.respuesta) # this returns None everytime. I've made sure the Respuesta objects above do exist
```

I know this might be very little code given, but there is so much that I'm not quite sure yet how to discriminate "relevant" code, first question...

Thank you in advance for any help provided! :)

Comment: Respuesta.objects.get(pk=2) the constant primary keys here might be the problem. Are you sure these Objects exist? Better to get your primary keys from objects you created previously as you cannot be sure these exact pks are used.

Comment: @H4kor I'm relaying in the fact that tests delete the testing database And recreate it in each manage.py test call. Yes, i'm sure a Respuesta object for each of those calls exists

Comment: Looks like refresh_from_db does not load relations.
Any cached relations are cleared from the reloaded instance. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db

Comment: Hmm interesting, si perhaps i should re-query my PreguntasPrueba instances? Or is there a more efficient way to accomplish the reload?